# UITableView does not automatically deselect the selected row when the table re-appears

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Normally a selected row in a `UITableView` gets deselected with an animation when the user pops back from the detail view.

However, in my case where I have a `UITableView` embedded in a `UIViewController` I have to do it manually in `viewWillAppear` like so:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // For some reason the tableview does not do it automatically
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow 
                                  animated:YES];  
}
```

Why is this and how to fix it?

Comment: iNoob, try storyboards, whenever you add a UITableViewController from the object browser you'll get that for free... However, many people seem to not know about this. Also see Rene's answer which explains it nicely.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

When your main ViewController is from type [UITableViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), it has [a property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewController/clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear) `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear`, which is per default `YES` - so it will clear the selection automatically.

This property is not available for an [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), i guess it's because it has no `ViewWillAppear` method either.

A [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIViewController) doesn't need this property because it has no `UITableView` originally.

conclusion: you'll have to implement it by yourself when you do not use a `UITableViewController`.

Comment: The reason `UITableView` does not have a `viewWillAppear` method is because that is the controller's, rather than the view's responsibility. Since `UITableView` is a UIView subclass, it does not deal with this mechanism.

Comment: `[myTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[myTableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];`

Comment: Note that as of Xcode 6.3 / iOS 8.3, the IB / storyboard based setting appears to be broken as the setting on the backing TableViewController is always set to true / never false, despite deselecting in the XIB / Storyboard.

Answer (score 35):

Do the deselection in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` instead of `viewWillAppear`:

```m
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
                  didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     //show the second view..
     [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES]; 
 }
```

Comment: This is not good as when user comes back it doesn't know where they are coming from. It should anime the deselection when popping back to show user previous location.

Answer (score 27):

In swift, you can add the following lines in your `viewWillAppear`

```
if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

In swift 2, it's without parantheses:

```
if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

In Swift 4 (and 3?) the function name was cleaned up:

```
if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: This is the only way to have the table view row's highlight fade away when the user goes back via sliding from the left edge of the screen

Comment: To follow iOS standard behaviour `animated` must be `true`.

Answer (score 4):

I dont think deselecting the selected row is automatic... I normally do it before pushing to the next view

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
        didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    // to do other things
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:yourNextViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Have a look at Rene's answer.

Comment: I like this solution the best because one doesn't need to store the selected indexPath.  Thanks!!

Comment: This is clever. Have a +1.

Comment: This is a terrible solution. When returning from `yourNextViewController` to the tableviewcontroller then there is no visual indication of what row was selected. It's better to do deselect in `viewWillAppear`.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong--deselecting the highlighted row is always "manual". If you look at Apple's sample code, you will see the same thing.

Comment: Yes it is automatic if the table is inside a UITableViewController See Rene's answer...

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3 / 4

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If table view selections are not being cleared in a subclass of `UITableViewController`, despite the fact that `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` is set to true, make sure to call the superclass version of `[UIViewController viewWillAppear:animated]` if you override that method.

If you fail to call the super version of that method, the value of `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` will have no effect as the work of clearing the table view selection is actually performed in `UITableViewController`'s implementation of `viewWillAppear`.

If your view controller does not inherit from `UITableViewController` you will need to clear the selection manually in `viewWillAppear`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use UITableView without UITableViewController, you can check Apple's sample code [Implementing Modern Collection Views](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/implementing_modern_collection_views) - EmojiExplorerViewController.swift `viewWillAppear` method for how to adopt animated deselection which is in-sync with view controller transition animation.

```swift
if let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first {
    if let coordinator = self.transitionCoordinator {
        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { context in
            self.collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        }) { (context) in
            if context.isCancelled {
                self.collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: [])
            }
        }
    } else {
        self.collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: animated)
    }
}
```