# UICollectionView didSelectItemAt/didUnselectItemAt doesn't work

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift3, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` and I implemented `collectionView(_:didSelectItemAt:)` and `collectionView(_:didDeselectItemAt:)`. When I scroll to the bottom of the collection view and select it, I want it to stay selected, so I don't call `collectionView(_:didDeselectItemAt:)` in `collectionView(_:didSelectItemAt:)`. Now, the problem is that when I scroll from the selected cell at the bottom to the cell at the top, the app crashes `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. My guts tell me this has to do with the dequeueing of cells under the hood.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! ServiceMenuItemCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 0/255.0, green: 138/255.0, blue: 217/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
            cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.9, y: 0.9)
        }, completion: { finish in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.05, animations: {
                cell.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            })
        })
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! ServiceMenuItemCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 177/255.0, green: 179/255.0, blue: 181/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }
```

How can I solve this correctly?

Comment: Show your code with crash. What you do in `collectionView(_:didSelectItemAt:)` method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix crash when tap to select row after scrolling the tableview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30972392/how-can-i-fix-crash-when-tap-to-select-row-after-scrolling-the-tableview). The logic of the crash is same. Also you can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40940014/why-will-diddeselectitemat-of-uicollectionview-throw-an-error-of-unexpected-foun?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I added code, @ArtemNovichkov. 

Honey, thanks for pointing me at the link, but I don't think it really is a duplicate, as the situation is different in my opinion.

Comment: the problem happens when you scroll down in the `didDeselectItemAt` and the cell becomes `nil` because it's no longer on the screen... so it's EXACTLY the same. Explain why it's not

Comment: When I scroll down and select an item, then scroll up to select another, both stay selected with your answer. That's when I do an optional unwrap instead of a hard unwrap of the cell.

Comment: `as!` <-- this is forced unwrapping...JUST try the answers mentioned, if it still failed then show the code failing from the other solutions

Comment: Yeah, I know. I implemented the code from the link you put here. I unwrap the cell with `if let cell = dequeue...` and it selects two cells now.

Comment: OK so you made *some* progress. however the outcome is weird. I don't know

Comment: Do I need to manually *deselect* the previous item, or..? Because that would become quite ugly code, and I would have to safely unwrap two cells, isn't that a memory hog?

Comment: I was about to say : *I don't know what you have done, but NO you shouldn't need to manually de-select a cell, you are listening to the callbacks from the collectionView. You must have done something which doesn't make it become deselected.*. **Then** I am now reading these 2 links :[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840614/why-does-uitableview-cell-remain-highlighted) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379510/uitableviewcell-doesnt-get-deselected-when-swiping-back-quickly)

Comment: and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106032/uitableview-does-not-automatically-deselect-the-selected-row-when-the-table-re-a) Hopefully someone can help us or we'll figure it out...

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems:

- a safe unwrapping in `didDeSelectItemAt` to avoid crashing
- For your intended purposes: undoing what you already have done in `DidSelectAtIndex`, in `didDeSelectItemAt`

### Code

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! ServiceMenuItemCell
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 0/255.0, green: 138/255.0, blue: 217/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
        cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.9, y: 0.9)
    }, completion: { finish in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.05, animations: {
            cell.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        })
    })
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! ServiceMenuItemCell else {return}
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 177/255.0, green: 179/255.0, blue: 181/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

in Addition about your problem of 2 cells being selected:

In your `didSelectItemAt` what are you doing? You ARE transforming the cell. So in your didSelect you have to undo whatever you have done. I mean your `didDeSelectItemAt` **is** working, but whatever mutation to the cell you have done must be undone. The `didDeselectItemAt` helps you to do it at the right time. I'm not sure how your selection works, but I think you know better, just undo it.

lemme know if it works